# Angular 2 : ng bootstrap drop down not working for me

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I have been trying to implement ng-bootstrap drop down using plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview.

Its not working, I am unable to find an issue

[image].

Below system.config.js code,

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      
    }
  });
})(this);
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbdDropdownConfig } from 'app/dropdown-config';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,NgbdDropdownConfig ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts code

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdDropdownConfig } from 'app/dropdown-config';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: ` <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <ngbd-dropdown-config></ngbd-dropdown-config>
  </div>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {  }
```

dropdown-config.ts code

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDropdownConfig} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-dropdown-config',
  templateUrl: 'app/dropdown-config.html',
  providers: [NgbDropdownConfig] // add NgbDropdownConfig to the component providers
})
export class NgbdDropdownConfig {
  constructor(config: NgbDropdownConfig) {
    // customize default values of dropdowns used by this component tree
    config.up = true;
    config.autoClose = false;
  }
}
```

dropdown-config.html

```html
<p>This dropdown uses customized default values.</p>

<div ngbDropdown>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu3" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Since there is no error message , I am unable to find issue. Can any one find out what is the issue could be . Thanks.

Comment: please correct link to plunker

Comment: What is the issue actually?

Comment: Sorry , here is the link, in this  last one, I have implemented  " Global configuration of dropdowns " https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown

Comment: Drop down of the toggle is not working at the same time, it does not showing any error.

Comment: You've provided the link to the working sample! To fix your problem we should start with your plunker having this issue. Would be more efficient than first doing work to reprode your problem and then fixing it

Comment: All my files in plunker  , here's the link https://embed.plnkr.co/e23NqXOUqtntnGBgr5gq/

Answer (score 4):

With the latest version(1.0.0-alpha.18) it is not working with me either. Downgrade to the previous version:

```
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.17 --save
```

and should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Manjula D
Just make below changes in dropdown-config.html

```
<div ngbDropdown>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu3" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3" ngbDropdownMenu>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **ngbDropdownMenu** is property added to "dropdown-menu" div.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

I ran

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

npm install --save bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2
```

template/html is provided here:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples

In styles.css:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Still things didn't work by this point so I re-ran

```
npm install
```

and things worked.